# Making calibre work with Aquaris M10 phablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, mtp, bq, m10, calibre

Sending books from calibre to the M10 phablet connected to a laptop through an USB cable does not work out of the box.

1. On the laptop, start calibre
2. Plug the tablet to the laptop using a USB cable
3. The M10 shows up in the file manager
4. Calibre detects the M10 and tries to writes the file driveinfo.calibre on the phablet, but fails with the folllowing error:

   ```
   calibre, version 2.56.0 ERROR: Error: Error communicating with device

   Failed to upload file named: driveinfo.calibre to (u'frieza',):
   2:PTP Layer error 2002: send_file_object_info(): Could not send object info.
   2:Error 2002: PTP: General Error

    Traceback (most recent call last):   File
    "site-packages/calibre/gui2/device.py", line 87, in run   File
    "site-packages/calibre/gui2/device.py", line 503, in _books   File
    "site-packages/calibre/devices/mtp/driver.py", line 216, in books
    File "site-packages/calibre/devices/mtp/driver.py", line 188, in get_driveinfo
      File "site-packages/calibre/devices/mtp/driver.py", line 178, in _update_drive_info
   File "site-packages/calibre/devices/mtp/driver.py", line 149, in put_calibre_file
   File "site-packages/calibre/devices/mtp/base.py", line 24, in synchronizer
   File "site-packages/calibre/devices/mtp/unix/driver.py", line 375, in put_file DeviceError: Failed to upload file named: driveinfo.calibre to (u'frieza',):
   2:PTP Layer error 2002: send_file_object_info(): Could not send object info.
   2:Error 2002: PTP: General Error
   ```

Meanwhile, trying to access the M10 files through the gnome file manager may or may not be successfull. (clicking on a folder can trigger an unknown libmtp error)

Running `dmesg` leads to:

```
[112904.984105] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[112905.112763] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2a47, idProduct=2008
[112905.112768] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[112905.112770] usb 2-1: Product: frieza
[112905.112771] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Ubuntu
[112905.112772] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: ML003442
[112906.779195] usb 2-1: usbfs: process 8790 (DeviceManager) did not claim interface 0 before use
[112906.944292] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[112907.073082] usb 2-1: usbfs: process 8790 (DeviceManager) did not claim interface 0 before use
[112907.073123] usb 2-1: usbfs: process 9023 (events) did not claim interface 0 before use
```

In the end I cannot push books on the M10 for reading.

Anyone got the thing working?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only in a very limited way.

PDF document push by calibre from Ubuntu desktop to the Bq M10 Ubuntu touch tablet fails.

But, PDF document push by calibre from Windows Vista desktop to tablet does not fail. However, even in this case, the desktop does not see that the files are on the tablet.